# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at xxxx.php:4

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying out this http://jsfiddle.net/fy63opLq/  The script works on this URL, but when I do it locally, it gave me this error message：**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at xxxx.php:4**
Which belongs to this line  **$(document).ready(function() {**
Can anyone help to identify what cause this error message?

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#thetable tbody').eq(0);
        var r = t.find('tr');
        var cols= r.length;
        var rows= r.eq(0).find('td').length;
        var cell, next, tem, i = 0;
        var tb= $('<tbody></tbody>');
        while(i<rows){
            cell= 0;
            tem= $('<tr></tr>');
            while(cell<cols){
                next= r.eq(cell++).find('td').eq(0);
                tem.append(next);
            }
            tb.append(tem);
            ++i;
        }
        $('#thetable').append(tb);
        $('#thetable').show();
    }); 

   </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="thetable" class="table table-striped">

 <tr>
    <td>Table header</td>
    <td>Table header</td>
    <td>Table header</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell2</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell3</td>
    <td>cell3</td>
    <td>cell3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to include jquery script first

Comment: In fiddle you may have add jquery, but at local you probably not.

Comment: add jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `jquery` library in your html file.

Add this line before the first `script` tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

From [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add jQuery to your script. add

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

To the top of your html and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your `head` tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the jQuery version `3.1.0` accordingly